# How to exclude .cpan folder from rsync?

Tags: backup, rsync, cpan, permission-denied

I use *rsync* to backup the home directory (ext4) of my Ubuntu installation. I use the following command to copy files and folders to a remote server (ext4).

```
$ rsync -rt --delete --delete-excluded --links \
  --exclude-from '/home/jjd/rsync-home-exclude.txt' \
  /home/jjd/ server:/volume1/backup-home
```

I defined some folders and files which can be ignored for the backup:

```
$ cat /home/jjd/rsync-home-exclude.txt
/home/jjd/.thumbnails/
/home/jjd/Downloads/.org.chromium.Chromium*
/home/jjd/.cpan
.cache/
*.swp
*.lock
*.tmp
/home/jjd/.local/share/recently-used.*
.TrueCrypt/.show-request-queue
.dropbox/command_socket
.dropbox/iface_socket
*.sock%
```

Nevertheless, *rsync* still reports the following errors:

```
rsync: opendir "/home/jjd/.cpan/build/local-lib-1.008009-Xl6GGK/inc" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "/home/jjd/.cpan/build/local-lib-1.008009-Xl6GGK/lib" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "/home/jjd/.cpan/build/local-lib-1.008009-Xl6GGK/t" failed: Permission denied (13)
IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1070) [sender=3.0.9]
```

Comment: Maybe you should remove the `/home/jjd` bit from the exclude file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `/home/jjd` from the exclude file. According to the rsync documentation, a leading slash does not apply to the root of the filesystem, but to the "root of the transfer".